# Access the TextBlock 's text at run time in DataTemplate of ItemsControl in WPF

Tags: wpf, time, datatemplate, textblock

Iam displaying messages in my WPF application
when a new message is added to the messages, i need to highlight it.so i want to dynamically get the text added to TextBlock

i have the xaml like this

```
 <ItemsControl Name="DialogItemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding Messages, Mode=OneWay}" Background="Transparent" 
                          BorderBrush="Transparent" TargetUpdated="DialogItemsControl_TargetUpdated">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate><!-- For ever message -->
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Margin="0,0,0,20">
                            <ItemsControl Name="SubDialogItemsControl"
                                  Foreground="{DynamicResource ButtonTextBrush}" 
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Lines,NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"
                                  Margin="0,0,0,12"
                                  Grid.Column="0">
                                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate><!-- For every line -->
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock Name="DialogMessageText" 
                                                   Text="{Binding NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" 
                                            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                                            Margin="0,2,0,2" 
                                            TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>                                    
                            </ItemsControl>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
```

and the code in the codebehind class is like this:

```
private void DialogItemsControl_TargetUpdated(object sender, System.Windows.Data.DataTransferEventArgs e)
        {  
          ItemsControl itemControl = sender as ItemsControl;

            ContentPresenter dp =   itemControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(itemControl.Items.CurrentItem) as ContentPresenter;

            // Finding textBlock from the DataTemplate that is set on that ContentPresenter
            DataTemplate myDataTemplate = dp.ContentTemplate;
            ItemsControl itc = (ItemsControl)myDataTemplate.FindName("SubDialogItemsControl", dp);
            if (itc != null && itc.ItemContainerGenerator.Status == System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.GeneratorStatus.ContainersGenerated)
            {
                ContentPresenter cp = itc.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(0) as ContentPresenter;
                DataTemplate dt = cp.ContentTemplate;
                TextBlock tb = dt.LoadContent() as TextBlock;               

                tb.TargetUpdated += new EventHandler<System.Windows.Data.DataTransferEventArgs>(myTextBlock_TargetUpdated);
            }            
        }

 void myTextBlock_TargetUpdated(object sender, System.Windows.Data.DataTransferEventArgs e)

       {

            TextBlock tb = sender as TextBlock;
           //When i access the text property of tb, its showing null, how to get the text
        }
```

When i access the text property of textblock in the target updated event of textblock, its showing null, how to read the text.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You tackle the problem from the wrong angle (and probably add a memory leak in the process since I don't see you unsubscribing to the event).

You need to create a Custom TextBlock, overriding the metadata of the Text property so that it changes the Background for a few seconds when the text string changes (through PropertyChangedCallback).

And then use that custom TextBlock in the DataTemplate of your ItemsControl.

**EDIT** - I thought other people could need this feature so here is a working example:

```
public class CustomTextBlock : TextBlock
    {
        static CustomTextBlock()
        {
            TextProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CustomTextBlock), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, 
                new PropertyChangedCallback(
                    (dpo, dpce) => 
                    {
                        //Flash the background to yellow for 2 seconds
                        var myTxtblk = dpo as CustomTextBlock;
                        if (myTxtblk != null)
                        {
                            myTxtblk.Background = Brushes.Yellow;
                            Task.Factory.StartNew(
                                () => 
                                {
                                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                                    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(
                                        new Action(() => 
                                        {
                                            myTxtblk.Background = Brushes.Transparent;
                                        }));
                                });
                        }
                    })));
        }
    }
```

Then you need to declare the right xmlns namespace in your XAML view, and you use it like a regular TextBlock:

```
<local:CustomTextBlock Text="{Binding MyDynamicText}"/>
```

It will flash yellow when MyDynamicText is modified (provided it raises PropertyChanged).